# How to network for senior level jobs?

Tags: networking, switzerland, initiative

I have a senior role in my company where I supervise a small team. I decided to look for opportunities in other companies where there are more possibilities for career development. I also decided to look at the Swiss job market.
However I have no network there. People say build a network on linkedin but I don't know what it means in reality. I send messages to some department heads on linkedin asking for consultation but I received no answer.
People say make cold call. What does it mean? Calling the company front desk and ask for the department head and ask them to hire me?

Can someone give some practical tips that I can use here? Consider that I'm an experienced person in my job but an introvert with bad networking skills.

Edit: I'm looking outside of the old school way of sending applications for job postings. I want to take the initiative, especially if I want to work in specific sectors or companies.

Comment: Why do you need to network for a job? Tons of job ads, apply to them.

Comment: See past questions about networking. The idea has been massively oversold. It isn't magic. It isn't the only or best way to find out about job opportunities. It can't be created without a basis for friendship and an understanding of you as a person and as a professional.  It isn't at all clear that it is worth explicitly investing time in; 
as opposed to just pursuing your professional interests and remembering to stay in touch with folks you meet that way.  You're confused for good reason; it's poorly defined and poorly justified.

Answer (score 6):

My take is that there are (at least) two sorts of networking in the world:

- Genuine, "old school" networking where you connect with peers in your industry on a long-term basis with no particular goal in mind. This is something which happens organically over a period of years.
- "Networking" as pushed by the influencer crowd in recent years which, if you believe the hype, just involves sending a few LinkedIn messages and magically you'll end up with 13 new job offers from FAANG companies.

If it's not obvious, the biggest difference between the two is the the first is for *mutual* benefit, while the second is purely for the benefit of the job applicant.

Yes, it's true that a non-trivial percentage of jobs are filled via networking one way or the other - but to think that you can suddenly start "networking" one day and that will produce a meaningful increase in the number of jobs you get offered is confusing causation and correlation. If you want to get a job this year, you're best off going through the traditional routes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I don't believe the 2nd type of networking is only to the benefit of the applicant. If I'm a person with good values also the company who'd hire me would benefit from it. At the end that's the whole idea behind hiring someone.

Comment: That applies to any hire though, and there's no evidence I'm aware of that indicates that applicants who apply via "networking" have better performance, ethics or anything else than applicants who apply via traditional means.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by working on your LinkedIn profile. Fill the parts of the profile that are incomplete. Add details about education and past jobs which may be missing and expand on the existing ones as needed. Mark your profile as looking for new opportunities.

You may start getting noticed by the recruiters if any of them are looking for profiles matching yours.

For the networking aspect, find and connect with people with common education and work history, basically people you know.

Next, instead of cold-calling, you can start looking for job postings on LinkedIn and apply for them.

You may also consider posting content on LinkedIn that showcases your experience and skills and which could be useful for peers with similar professional background. This should help you get noticed and likely network with people from similar background. Relevant content posted regularly and using appropriate tags should make your profile discoverable to peers with similar background or people consuming that kind of content.

This strategy should hopefully put you in front of potential work opportunities.

Answering your specific questions:

> I also decided to look at the Swiss job market.

Consider changing your location in the profile to the region where you are looking for job. This may put you in front of people looking to hire profile similar to yours.

Also, consider mentioning in your profile/bio about the kind of experience you have and the kind of job you are looking for.

> I send messages to some department heads on LinkedIn asking for consultation but I received no answers.

Applying to open jobs matching your expertise may be a better option here. In case there are any work-permit/visa requirements before you can be work in the location, make sure to mention them.

> Can someone give some practical tips that I can use here?

The tips shared above may not be full-proof but a general guideline to set you towards the correct direction. Make sure to experiment, learn and adapt as you go.

Wish you the very best for your next endeavour.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. But I want to do initiative application or offers to specific companies that I'm interested in, and not just can companies I have friends in or companies they find me

Comment: @Bob Look for job posting matching your profile in the desired companies on LinkedIn and on the official website.

Comment: @Bob Unless you are an exceptional individual, preferably with an established reputation in your field or with credentials like a long history of successful patent applications, "Initiative applications" really don't work well in big companies. They hire to fit specific needs in specific departments, rather than picking someone and then finding a position for them, and no one person knows all the openings that  exist except their hiring office. You're excited about working for them? Great; so are lots of others; focus on applying specifically for jobs where you're exactly what they need.

Comment: The days when CDC's Director of Research answered his own phone and was willing to spend half an hour talking to a kid who'd had the guts to try calling him ended long ago.